# Control of reflected wave through metasurface

Tags: metamaterials

When a wave impinges on a metasurface, one can tune the metasurface to control the direction of the reflected wave. I would like to know whether it is possible to make a 3D control of the direction. I mean if the incident direction is on plane (x,y), can we tune the reflected wave direction to be on a different plane?

Comment: you would require multiple mirrors

Comment: maybe a diffraction grating? if does qualify as metasurface